# Circle user avatar issue

Tags: c++, qt, windows

I want to make `QLabel`  with the image circle:

**Code:**

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
QPixmap avatarPixmap(":/Icon/default_avatar.png");
label->setPixmap(avatarPixmap);
label->setStyleSheet("border: 0.5px solid red; border-radius: 50%; background-clip: padding;");
```

[image: 0_1517048799005_2018-01-27_122604.png]

It only rounds the `QLabel`, not the image. How to fix it? Thanks.

**Update:**

The only way is to override the `paintEvent` for `QLabel`

**Code:**

```
void AccountImage::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPixmap pixmap(":/Icon/default_avatar.png");
    QBrush brush(pixmap);
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setBrush(brush);
    painter.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, width(), height(), 100, 100);
    QLabel::paintEvent(event);
}
```

[image: 0_1517054607704_2018-01-27_140145.png]

The image is rounded but not properly scaled. Any ideas?

Comment: @liliscent

What do you mean by modifying the image?

Comment: @liliscent

Applying border-image to `QLabel` doesn't work in my case, I need to change the default image later by code. Is there way to repaint `QLabel`?

Comment: @liliscent

I have override the `paintEvent` for `QLabel`. I will add the changes to my main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set mask on the label like:

```
int w = // set the width here
int h = // set the height here
QRect *rct = new QRect(0, 0, w, h);
QRegion *reg = new QRegion(*rct, QRegion::Ellipse);
label->setMask(*reg);
```

see: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setMask

Comment: It's looks good but the image edges is sharpen. Any ideas how to smooth it?

Comment: Regarding Pixmap you could try with QPixmap::transformed()  with a Qt::SmoothTransformation -> this gives you a transformed copy of Pixmap which you can use for your label. But I'm not sure if this fixes the border itself. Maybe you could also try with border-style:outset. If this doesnt work, maybe you could define your own Widget, override paintEvent and draw the stuff itself by using antialiasing.

Comment: Ok. I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have set it properly by overriding `QLabel paintEvent`. I will post code here so users can find a solution faster.

Answer (score 1):

The solution by overriding `QLabel` `paintEvent` method.

**Code:**

```
void AccountImage::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPixmap pixmap(":/Icon/my_avatar.png");
    QPixmap scaled = pixmap.scaled(width(), height(), Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
    QBrush brush(scaled);
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setBrush(brush);
    painter.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, width(), height(), 100, 100);
    QLabel::paintEvent(event);
}
```

**Result:**

[image]